# How to update Map Value in Flutter Firebase Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

**I have a Map object in my document data. Like Below**

[image]

I have to add a new user bid to the same map without erasing old data but the code I used was replacing the whole Map with the new value. Any suggestions on how to achieve my goal.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('products')
.doc(widget.product.uid).update({
  'bids': {
  auth.currentUser?.email:
      currentPrice.toString()
  }
});
```

Comment: Ok that means, I have to update Map myself and then add it to firestore. Is it ?

Comment: Ok thanks for the help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use dot notation to update a nested field:

```
const userEmail = auth.currentUser?.email;
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('products')
.doc(widget.product.uid).update({
  'bids.${userEmail}':  currentPrice.toString()
});
```

> Dot notation allows you to update a single nested field without overwriting other nested field. If you update a nested field without dot notation, you will overwrite the entire map field

References:

1. [Update fields in nested objects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects)
2. [FlutterFire Documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#field-values)

To update fields with `.` in their keys:

```
var fPath = FieldPath(["bids", "user.name@domain.tld"]);
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('products').doc(widget.product.uid).update(fPath, currentPrice.toString());
```

Comment: Definitely more efficient than my solution. Use this

Comment: @MadduSwaroop can you share your updated code?  Also try restarting your emulator or app. Using dot notation should update that field only and not overwrite others. It's mentioned in both Firebase's docs and FlutterFire's.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to save : ) My bad.

Comment: You are simply awesome Thanks for the help.

Comment: Bro this time another map was creating inside bids because of . in mail id? Any way to avoid it

Comment: @MadduSwaroop You need to use FieldPath. I'm not sure how that's done in Flutter but some I did some quick searches and found that. Check my updated answer. But thing is you use FieldPath. That works for me using Javascript SDK.